# SQL does not take in positive strings

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, substr, charindex

I am using SQL Server 2012. I have a trap where I get the minus and put it at the front of my values in a set string, however there are also values that don't have a minus, and they come up as nulls in my column.
I need a way to not take in these positive values as it is a standard procedure and I only need the minus values in my query.

My code is

```
CASE 
   WHEN CHARINDEX('-', SUBSTRING([Txt], 147, 10)) > 0   
      THEN '-' + REPLACE(LTRIM(RTRIM(SUBSTRING([TXT], 147, 9))), ',','') 
END AS [Open_Amount]
```

In my query the positive values come up as "nulls" which I don't want, I want the entire row ignored if `open_amount` is a positive value. Is there a specific else statement I can put in my case or is there another way? If it helps using views/cross applies isn't an option unfortunately for this data structure

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Your code and your description seem to have little in common.

Comment: Hi Gordon, desired result would be having Open Amount column just showing minus values, hence my case statement, however there are positive values in that substring which i need to essentially "drop" from my query, i cant have them coming in as nulls as i need the entire row dropped(that has a positive value)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Is this what you want?

```
(case when Substring([Txt], 147, 10) like '%-%' 
      then '-' + Replace(LTrim(RTRIM(Substring([TXT], 147, 9))), ',', '') 
      else Replace(LTrim(RTRIM(Substring([TXT], 147, 9)))
 end) as [Open_Amount]
from db.txt
```

If you want to keep only negative rows, then use:

```
where substring([Txt], 147, 10) like '%-%'
```

Comment: Hi Gordon, thanks for your response, unfortunately not . using that code will just pull in the positive values, where i want them ignored. so essentially i want it to look for a minus in 147-157 like you did and put it to the front, but if there is no minus, i need it to not bring in the values and therefore that row would be skipped

Comment: @Git_Hub-96 . . . If you want to skip a row you need to use a `where` clause, not a `case` expression.

Comment: how would i go about this? would the way to do it be : in my case, in else set it to put all positive values as 'test' then in my where go  "LTrim(RTRIM(Substring(txt, 147, 9))) <>'%test%'" im not sure that would work? thanks